# Monitoring system for build, source control and integration servers

Tags: language-agnostic, monitoring

Do you know about any lightweight system that will monitor servers in terms of disk space, CPU usage, uptime/availability?

I'm talking mainly about DB, Subversion, Hudson, integration, qa and build servers. All the advanced server monitoring tools are very hard to configure and use. So I'm looking for something simple.

Open source tools are preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is very good.  Super flexible and can monitor just about anything.  It can also execute workflows when certain events/alerts happen.  And it's free.

Comment: I've installed it but the interface is not so nice. And it seems that all the configuration is through files or you have to install an addon. Do you use such an addon ? Do you have any suggestions about the interface ? Skins maybe ?

Comment: The interface can be clunky.  We used config files for all configuration.  It's a PITA to setup (as are all monitoring tools) but once it's done you rarely need to do wholesale changes.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [Hostmonitor](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/).
Simple to setup, use and at a very reasonably price.

> HostMonitor can check any TCP service,
>   ping a host, check a route, monitor
>   Web, FTP, Mail, DNS servers. It can
>   check the available disk space,
>   monitor size of a file or folder,
>   check integrity of your files and web
>   site; it tests your SQL servers,
>   monitors network traffic and much,
>   much more.

Comment: Its server/dashboard only runs on windows which is big disadvantage for us. It doesn't have a free version and the GUI is old Win95-style. I hope that its ease of use is the only thing worth checking. Sorry.

Comment: No need to appologize, I don't get any money out of it <g>.